# Check if two files are the same

Tags: c, string-comparison

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{

        int status = 0;
        FILE * fPointer;
        FILE * gPointer;
        fPointer = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
        gPointer = fopen("file2.txt", "r");

        char singleLine[150];
        char secondLine[150];

        while(fgets(singleLine,150,fPointer)!=NULL && fgets(secondLine,150,gPoi$
        {
                //fgets(singleLine,150,fPointer);
                //fgets(secondLine,150,gPointer);
                printf("singleLine: %s\n",singleLine);
                printf("secondLine: %s\n",secondLine);
                if (singleLine !=  secondLine)
                {
                        status = 1;
                }
        }
        printf("final status: %d\n", status);
        if (status == 0)
        {
                printf("same\n");
        }
        else if (status == 1)
        {
                printf("not same\n");
        }
        fclose(fPointer);
        fclose(gPointer);
        return 0;
}
```

The contents of both files are "hello" and "hello". But for some reason the output I get is

> singleLine: hello
>   secondLine: hello
>   final status: 1

which equals "not the same".
I checked by printing what `singleLine` and `secondLine` are at each iteration and they are the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using `fgets`?  There is no reason to compare the file one line at a time.  Use `fread` and compare larger blocks.

Comment: I notice that you use `nano`. You probably shouldn't copy from it, it cuts of$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following doesn't quite work as you think it does:

```c
if (singleLine !=  secondLine)
```

That is because `singleLine` and `secondLine` are arrays (treated as strings). Equality/inequality operators in C, when used for arrays, simply check whether the two arrays reside at the same address in memory (i.e. are the same variable). Which in your case are not, so your *if* statement is always true.

Since you are treating both arrays as strings, the correct function to use is `strcmp` or `strncmp`, both defined in `<string.h>`. This is the standard way of performing string comparisons in C (hence the name of the functions).

Your if statement, in this case should be:

```c
if (strcmp(singleLine, secondLine) != 0)
{
    status = 1;
}
```